# Pre append regex pattern to split and map case class to splitted

Tags: scala, split

I want to split following string which takes the form

```
val str = "X|blnk_1|blnk_2|blnk_3|blnk_4|time1|time2|blnk_5|blnk_6|blnk_7|blnk_8| |Z01|Str1|01|001|NE]|[HEX1|HEX2]|[NA|001:1000|123:456|[00]|]|Z01|Str2|02|002|NE]|[HEX3|HEX4]|[NA|002:1001|234:456|[01]|]|Z02|02|z2|Str|Str|"
```

This string always start with X and split positions are Z01,Z02,...,Z0D

```
str.split("""\|Z0[1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|A|B|C|D]{1}\|""") foreach println
```

Here there could be no ordering of the position of Z01,...,Z0D  appear in the string.

The split gives the desired result :

```
X|blnk_1|blnk_2|blnk_3|blnk_4|time1|time2|blnk_5|blnk_6|blnk_7|blnk_8|
Str1|01|001|NE]|[HEX1|HEX2]|[NA|001:1000|123:456|[00]|]
Str2|02|002|NE]|[HEX3|HEX4]|[NA|002:1001|234:456|[01]|]
02|z2|Str|Str|
```

However I want to map X, Z01,... to case classes. Since there is no ordering there is no way of identifying to which case class split would need to map(can't use length of individual splits ).

I expect my split to have following output :

```
X|blnk_1|blnk_2|blnk_3|blnk_4|time1|time2|blnk_5|blnk_6|blnk_7|blnk_8|
Z01|[Str1|01|001|NE]|[HEX1|HEX2]|[NA|001:1000|123:456|[00]|]|
Z01|[Str2|02|002|NE]|[HEX3|HEX4]|[NA|002:1001|234:456|[01]|]|
Z01|02|z2|Str|Str|
```

so that the result could be mapped to case class with the help of the preappended  pattern.

For example:

```
case class X( ....)
case class Z01(val1: String, val2: String, val3: String)
case class Z02(val1: Int, val2: String, val3: String,val4:String)
.................
```

`X|blnk_1|blnk_2|blnk_3|blnk_4|time1|time2|blnk_5|blnk_6|blnk_7|blnk_8|` maps to `case class X`
and 
    `Z01|[Str1|01|001|NE]|[HEX1|HEX2]|[NA|001:1000|123:456|[00]|]|` maps to case class `Z01`

and in the end result should be in the form of ordered and similar groups to be taken as a array of particular case class.

```
X
Array[Z01]
Array[Z02]
......
......
```

Comment: How about the simple looking `str.split("Z")` and then manually parse it?

Comment: @Jatin This is actually part of Spark dataframe transformation. I would like to do it in single run.

Comment: I can't confirm it. But may be it may consume lesser clock cycles. Regex is a serial time killer. Split by a single character does not internally invoke regex but simple string iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative it might be an option to get your values by matching them:

[`(?:Z0[1-9A-D]|^X).*?(?=\|Z0[1-9A-D]|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/o7eIWO/1/)

This matches:

- `(?:Z0[1-9A-D]|X\|)` In a non capturing group match `Z0` and list the possible options in a character class or `|` X at the start `^`of the line
- `.*?` Match any character one or more times non greedy
- `(?=\|Z0[1-9A-D]|$)` Positive lookahead which asserts that what follows is a pipe `|` followed by `Z0` and a character from the character list or `|` the end of the line `$`

For example:

```
val re = """(?:Z0[1-9A-D]|^X).*?(?=\|Z0[1-9A-D]|$)""".r
val str = "X|blnk_1|blnk_2|blnk_3|blnk_4|time1|time2|blnk_5|blnk_6|blnk_7|blnk_8| |Z01|Str1|01|001|NE]|[HEX1|HEX2]|[NA|001:1000|123:456|[00]|]|Z01|Str2|02|002|NE]|[HEX3|HEX4]|[NA|002:1001|234:456|[01]|]|Z02|02|z2|Str|Str|"

re.findAllIn(str) foreach println
```

That will result in:

```
X|blnk_1|blnk_2|blnk_3|blnk_4|time1|time2|blnk_5|blnk_6|blnk_7|blnk_8| 
Z01|Str1|01|001|NE]|[HEX1|HEX2]|[NA|001:1000|123:456|[00]|]
Z01|Str2|02|002|NE]|[HEX3|HEX4]|[NA|002:1001|234:456|[01]|]
Z02|02|z2|Str|Str|
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/GIDPB50729)

Answer (score 2):

How about this idea?

```
val x = str.split("""\|Z0[1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|A|B|C|D]{1}\|""") // actual string splits
val y = """\|Z0[1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|A|B|C|D]{1}\|""".r.findAllIn(str).toArray // delimiters Array

val final_data = x.slice(1, x.size).zip(y).map(x => x._2+x._1).toList // taking actual splits except first one .... and then zipping and concatenating with delimiters like below. 
/*
    List(|Z01|Str1|01|001|NE]|[HEX1|HEX2]|[NA|001:1000|123:456|[00]|], |Z01|Str2|02|002|NE]|[HEX3|HEX4]|[NA|002:1001|234:456|[01]|], |Z02|02|z2|Str|Str|) */
```

the first `|` in the final_data can be removed with `subString`